# OpenEMR 4.1.1 and Lab Results

Tags: php

This might be a pretty straight forward question to someone who knows openEMR. I am trying to connect openEMR 4.1.1 to send tests and receive Lab Results from our contracted laboratory. Under Administration -> Globals -> Connectors there is an option 'Lab Exchange Results' but it doesn't do anything.

**Problems:**

In code I can see there is a module to read HL7 directly into openEMR but don't know what configurations I need to provide to make it work.

**What I have tried**

Of Course, I have googled and surfed through dozens of articles but nothing directing clearly what I need to do or I am not able to get it.

**Information I can provide**

Apart from problem statement, I am attaching a configuration area screenshot and if someone can help me setting that up OR even tell me how I can make openEMR interface with my laboratory using HL7, I'll really appreciate that.
[image]
Thanks,

-Rahi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case if somebody is looking for the answer...I have found it in the form of Procedures module in openemr 4.1.2.

Comment: Thanks Rahi, did you find any other useful documentation on how to do this? I too am new.

Comment: @IainDuncan There isn't much documentation on Labs/Procedures modules. If you are a programmer then you should look at lab_orders module code and database tables prefixed 'procedure_'.